# Unable to set text in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to call a function from my mainActivity to change a TextView in one of my fragments. I have read a couple posts on the best way of doing it but for some reason, none of them seem to work for me. I know the function is working because once a press the button the toast comes up but for some reason the text won't change. I was wondering what the issue could be, or if I am just missing an additional step.

here is the method being called in my mainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tab1Fragment.OnCalcClickListener{
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdpater;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
Tab1Fragment tab1Fragment = new Tab1Fragment();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting");

    //initializing FragmentManager so the fragments can communicate
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, tab1Fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    //declare sections page adapter
    mSectionsPageAdpater = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //Set up the view pager with the sections adapter
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setUpViewPager(mViewPager);

    //create a tab layout object and set it's id to tabs (mainActivity.xml)
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    //
}

// create a sections page view adapter
private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
     SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Day");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "Info");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "Week");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//initialise calculator object
Calculator mainCalculator = new Calculator();


@Override
public void calculateClick(int to_calculate) {
    switch (to_calculate){
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mainCalculator.freqDay = mainCalculator.freqDay + 1;
            mainCalculator.freqWeek = mainCalculator.freqWeek + 1;
            mainCalculator.getTotalDay();
            tab1Fragment.updateInfo();
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my fragment

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment implements 
View.OnClickListener{
private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";
//Establishing the buttons & Methods
Button btn1;
Button btn2;
TextView dayView;
OnCalcClickListener onCalcClickListener;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);


    //Connecting the buttons to the xml
    btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    dayView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_Sales_Day);
    return view;
}

//Onclick listener for buttons
public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    btn1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(listener);
}


//method that will bring data back from activity and set the text
public void updateInfo(){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"65", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dayView.setText("test");

}
```

Comment: And how did you initialize `tab1Fragment`?

Comment: Another question: Which `Toast` does  appear? "working" or "65" !?

Comment: Both appear, I added the second toast to see if I was able to call my updatInfo function from the activity. It is working but for some reason it just won't set the text to "test".

Answer (score 0):

To make calls to methods from your fragment in the activity class you need something like this:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
        // Do something here to display that article

        ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the activity is calling the `updateArticleView` method from the fragment, instead of your `updateInfo` method, but you will get the idea.

Also pay attention to the `one-pane` scenario, where you need to swap the content and push the arguments using a `Bundle` object.

See [Deliver a Message to a Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver) for more details.

Comment: my bad, I did not post the rest of my main activity. My fragment is managing to receive the string from my main activity but for some reason the textView is not updating. would you know if this is caused by the onCreate function?

Comment: @l34lo1 The issue is that you are always creating a new `Fragment`, in your activity using: `Tab1Fragment tab1Fragment = new Tab1Fragment();`. You should have the case with the lookup of the fragment too, since it is managed by android framework. See the branch using: `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.tab1_fragment);` like I mentioned in my answer. You need both of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the fragment set a tag to it like this:

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, frag, "TAG").commit();
```

While updating the textview get the instance of fragment using `findFragmentByTag()`

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");
fragment.updateInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working for me. It seems my issue is with the textview not updating.

Comment: did u try debugging the code? Run your app in debugger mode and check if the debugger is going inside updateInfo() method or not